# On Hover jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a menu. On hover I need to add letter-spacing style.

Menu:

```
    <ul class="whitedropdown-menu">
        <li class="disabledMenu"><a class="ng-binding">Menu 1</a></li>
        <li class="disabledMenu"><a class="ng-binding">Menu 2</a></li>
        <li class="activemenu"><a class="ng-binding">Menu 3</a></li>
        <li class="activemenu">
            <div class="icon"><i class="fa ico"></i></div>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)">Menu 4</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

jQuery code: To detect mac chrome and function for hover

```
    if(navigator.platform.toLowerCase().indexOf('mac') > -1 && navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome') > -1)
    {
        $(".whitedropdown-menu > li.activemenu").hover((function() {
          $(this).find("a").css("letter-spacing", "-1px");
        }), function() {
          $(this).find("a").css("letter-spacing", "0px");
        });
    }
```

It is not working properly. When i hover on Menu 3 It works fine. But when i hover on Menu 4, Menu 3 is getting affected. How can i resolve this?

Please Help,
Thanks

Comment: Use `$(".whitedropdown-menu > li.activemenu").on('mouseenter', function() { ... });` instead of hover

Comment: @Anton That happened when i copied and pasted code to stackoverflow. I also have a class in same name

Comment: I'm on a Mac using Chrome and your mark-up/javascript work fine for me. http://jsfiddle.net/jpattishalljr/c9bbowos/ Is there more CSS?

Comment: Remove div from menu 4 and use icon class with <i class="icon fa ico"> tag

Answer (score 0):

This may help , check it out :

```
    <script>
    $("#whitedropdown-menu > li.activemenu").mouseenter(function() {

        $(this).find("a").css("letter-spacing", "-1px");

    }).mouseleave(function() {

        $(this).find("a").css("letter-spacing", "0px");

    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>ThisTest</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    ul{list-style-type: none}
    ul ul{display: none}
    ul ul ul{display: none}

</style>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

 $("ul li").click(function(){
     var myClass = $(this).attr("class");

     if(typeof myClass == 'undefined'){
        $(this).attr("class","active"); 
    $(this).siblings().find("ul").css("display","none");

     $(this).find("ul").css("display","block");
     $(this).find("ul").find("ul").css("display","none");
     event.stopImmediatePropagation();

     }else{
        if(myClass == 'active'){
        $(this).attr("class","inactive"); 
                 $(this).siblings().find("ul").css("display","none");

     $(this).find("ul").css("display","none");
     $(this).find("ul").find("ul").css("display","none");
     event.stopImmediatePropagation();

        }else{
            $(this).attr("class","active"); 
                 $(this).siblings().find("ul").css("display","none");

     $(this).find("ul").css("display","block");
     $(this).find("ul").find("ul").css("display","none");
     event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        }
     }
 });


}); 
</script>
</head>

<body>

<ul>
    <li><a>India</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a>Sachin</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a>Batting</a>
                   <ul>
                    <li><a>Tests</a></li>
                    <li><a>ODI</a></li>
                    <li><a>T20</a></li>
                   </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a>Bowling</a>
                    <ul>
                    <li><a>Tests</a></li>
                    <li><a>ODI</a></li>
                    <li><a>T20</a></li>
                   </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a>Dravid</a>
          <ul>
                <li><a>Batting</a>
                    <ul>
                    <li><a>Tests</a></li>
                    <li><a>ODI</a></li>
                    <li><a>T20</a></li>
                   </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a>Bowling</a>
                    <ul>
                    <li><a>Tests</a></li>
                    <li><a>ODI</a></li>
                    <li><a>T20</a></li>
                   </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a>Saurav</a>
          <ul>
                <li><a>Batting</a>
                    <ul>
                    <li><a>Tests</a></li>
                    <li><a>ODI</a></li>
                    <li><a>T20</a></li>
                   </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a>Bowling</a>
                    <ul>
                    <li><a>Tests</a></li>
                    <li><a>ODI</a></li>
                    <li><a>T20</a></li>
                   </ul>
                </li>
            </ul></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a>Australia</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a>Ponting</a>
          <ul>
                <li><a>Batting</a>
                    <ul>
                    <li><a>Tests</a></li>
                    <li><a>ODI</a></li>
                    <li><a>T20</a></li>
                   </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a>Bowling</a>
                    <ul>
                    <li><a>Tests</a></li>
                    <li><a>ODI</a></li>
                    <li><a>T20</a></li>
                   </ul>
                </li>
            </ul></li>
        <li><a>Steve</a>
          <ul>
                <li><a>Batting</a>
                    <ul>
                    <li><a>Tests</a></li>
                    <li><a>ODI</a></li>
                    <li><a>T20</a></li>
                   </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a>Bowling</a>
                    <ul>
                    <li><a>Tests</a></li>
                    <li><a>ODI</a></li>
                    <li><a>T20</a></li>
                   </ul>
                </li>
            </ul></li>
        <li><a>Clarke</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a>South Africa</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a>Croze</a></li>
            <li><a>Smith</a></li>
            <li><a>Cock</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a>Batting</a>
                    <ul>
                    <li><a>Tests</a></li>
                    <li><a>ODI</a></li>
                    <li><a>T20</a></li>
                   </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a>Bowling</a>
                   <ul>
                    <li><a>Tests</a></li>
                    <li><a>ODI</a></li>
                    <li><a>T20</a></li>
                   </ul>
                </li>
            </ul></li>

        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's better to include some context/explanation with code as this makes the answer more useful for the OP and for future readers.

Comment: Following @EJoshuaS's comment, please see here for [How to Write a Good Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) on StackOverflow.

Comment: Does this piece of code have anything to do with the question asked? The question was about adjusting `letter-spacing` but there's no `letter-spacing` in your code.